# Laravel Undefined class constant MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo

I am getting an error. Local it works, but not on production.

Does anyone have an idea?

PHP Version 7.1.14-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Mysql Version 5.7.21

Error:

```
production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Undefined class constant ‘MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE’ in /data/www/xxx/config/database.php:50
```

Database:

```
    'default' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
        'options'   => array(
            \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
        ),
    ],
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have pdo_mysql extension enabled in php

Comment: @Vishal i can retrieve data from dbase

Comment: MySQL Version in php info is 5.0.XX ..Try apt-get install php-mysql

Comment: I don't get it, sorry, but now i have version MYSQL is 5.7.21, what is this version? Is this old?

Comment: Try installing/enabling pdo module again using these commands
apt-get install php7.0-mysql
phpenmod pdo_mysql
service apache2 restart ..After this print phpinfor again

Comment: I can't, the hosting, the app works fine at 7.0 but on 7.1 it gives the error

Answer (score 1):

> Install or enable PDO module using these commands

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mysql

sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using a PHP version other than the latest**, you have to specify the version with the extensions you want to download.

Example, in Ubuntu 24.04, I needed to use PHP 7.4.  After getting all that set up, to get pdo support working, I had to enter:

```
sudo apt install php7.4-mysql
```

Unlike the other examples where you simply enter php-mysql.